# Completion stops working in /root directory

Tags: bash, debian, tab-completion

If I am in a root terminal `su`, then everything is fine: completion is OK everywhere.

The problem arises if, as a normal user, I try to use `sudo` to reach the `/root/` directory , for instance, if I want to open a file like `/root/.selected_editor`.

When I reach /ro completion it is still OK and writes `/root/`, but then it stops working. If I finish writing the Linux Bash command I want to execute by hand, then this command is working fine.

```
root@Xfce:~# cat .se(lected_editor) ---> completion is OK
xxx@Xfce:~$ sudo cat /ro(ot/)  --->  completion is still OK
xxx@Xfce:~$ sudo cat /root/.se(   ) --->  completion has stopped working
```

To see if I could list what's inside `/root/`, I tried  `sudo ls -a /root/` and I got the list all right. Then I tried on another laptop with Debian 11 installed, and it behaved exactly the same way.

System: Laptop with [Debian 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_11_(Bullseye)) (Bullseye) and [Xfce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce)

Answer (score 22):

Tab-completion of file names isn't done by asking "sudo cat" to provide suggestions; it's done directly by the shell that you're currently typing commands into. And since *that's* not running under "sudo" yet, it does not have privileges to access the contents of `/root`, just like a `ls /root` or `echo /root/*` wouldn't.

Always keep in mind that `sudo` isn't just a special shell keyword telling it to do things as root. It is a whole **separate program** that needs to be run in the same way as `ps` or whatever. (For example, running `sudo cat something` will only make the shell run /bin/sudo; then sudo obtains root privileges and runs the actual /bin/cat.)

Therefore its effects are only visible when the command is being run, and it can only affect the part of the command line that was provided to sudo. It doesn't see the rest of a pipeline in "sudo this | that" (that's split up by the shell), it can't affect file redirections (those were done by the shell before 'sudo' runs), and it can't affect tab completion (also done by the shell before it launches 'sudo').

(Though for some commands, Bash may have custom 'bash-completion' scripts which *may* choose to, e.g., obtain the list of files or services or processes by running some helper through sudo, but such scripts aren't being used in this example. You're dealing only with Bash's built-in file name completion.)

Comment: Yes, that's the good answer. Another common confusion with sudo'ed command: `sudo /some/priviledged_directory/some_program > /some/priviledged_directory/outputfile` : the > part is done by the current shell, and therefore may not be possible (as the current shell's user may not have write access there, or even traversal rights to reach that directory), and only the `some_program` command is sudo'ed.